# Проблема с растяжением экрана в приложении на Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

У меня есть приложение, в котором можно пролистывать экран вверх или вниз.

Когда я дохожу до верхней или нижней границы, в противоположном конце экрана происходит растяжение, и контент даже выходит за рамку экрана.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это отключить.

Также добавлю код layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hdw.whaile.hdwnetweb.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ManiFest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HDWnetweb"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.UiModeManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    public static boolean isDark = false;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        WebSettings webset = webView.getSettings();
        webset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webset.setSaveFormData(false);
        webset.setSavePassword(false);

        webView.clearFormData();

        determineTheme();

        if (isDark) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loading_dark.html");
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loading.html");
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.clearHistory();

            if (isDark) {
                webView.loadUrl("https://hdwebnet.ru/phone/index?dark=true");
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl("https://hdwebnet.ru/phone/index");
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    private class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String link = "hdwebnet.ru";
            if (url.startsWith("file:///") || url.startsWith("https://" + link) || url.startsWith("http://" + link)) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            if (isDark) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error_page_dark.html");
            } else {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error_page.html");
            }
        }
    }

    private void determineTheme() {
        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;

        switch (currentNightMode) {
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                isDark = false;
                break;

            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                isDark = true;
                break;

            default:
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
            if (uiModeManager != null && uiModeManager.getNightMode() == UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
                isDark = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И также скрины проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: В данном случае, в дополнение к коду, не помешали бы скриншоты приложения, демонстрирующие проблему.

Comment: Добавил код и скрины

Comment: Вы уверены что это не проблема web-разметки, которую вы крутите в WebView?

Comment: Да я точно уверен, если открыть страницу в любом браузере такого не происходит

Comment: Было бы довольно круто если бы кто-то мне помог :)

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть связано либо со стилями в вашем веб-контенте, либо со специфической реализацией WebView на конкретном устройстве или версии Android.

Это может быть связано со стилями веб-страницы, то вам стоит проверить CSS вашей веб-страницы, особенно свойства, относящиеся к прокрутке (overflow, height, max-height и т.д.), и убедиться, что они настроены таким образом, чтобы не было растяжения контента.